# Why do these subscripts look smaller ? ＋ <sub>[用言句]</sub>

Tags: bug

```
     ( I had to choose a tag, so i picked the [bug] tag,
       but this is a cute anomaly that i hope will not go away. )
```

In the text at the very end, [用言句] (both occurrences) looks bold & smaller than the other subscripts.  (Ok, maybe not bold)  . . .  Why is this?

( Only in IE, with Chrome the subscripts look the same size. )

<sub>（体言句）</sub> [用言句]  <sub>[用言句]</sub> Text<sub>[用言句]</sub>

---

Knowing these rules immediately helped me parse these sentences:

1. そのモンスター撃退で経験値は何点来る？
2. そのモンスター撃退で来る経験値は何点？

   ```
     （１）　文　＝　（連用句）＋（体言句）＋　[用言句]
   ```

   1. <sub>（連用句）</sub>( そのモンスター撃退で )  ＋ <sub>（体言句）</sub>(経験値は) ＋<sub>（体言句）</sub>(何点)   ＋  <sub>[用言句]</sub>[来る]？
   2. <sub>（体言句）</sub>( そのモンスター撃退で来る経験値は )  ＋<sub>（体言句）</sub>(何点)？ -- ( <sub>[用言句]</sub> [ですか]? is probably omitted)

Comment: Can you take a screenshot for those of us without IE? (Can't detect any difference in Firefox either.)